# Sort Data by date with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I will try to keep this as simple as possible and cause no confusion. 
I have over 35,000 rows and 15 columns of data but I am going to provide a very simple case of what I am trying to do.

Basically, I want to sort my dates in column A in ascending order, but then also have the data corresponding to a date sorted to "follow" it to its new row location. I want this to be done using VBA code.

```
Simple Case

Raw Data
Column A    Column B
Jan 5       15
Jan 3       45
Jan 1       7
Jan 10      12
Jan 7       30


Expected Sorted Data
Column A    Column B
Jan 1       7
Jan 3       45
Jan 5       15
Jan 7       30
Jan 10      12
```

I have looked all over and can not find a good way to do this. Any and all help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Use the sort function in Excel and make sure you have the appropriate columns selected - not just the one to sort on.

Comment: Make sure that the data in column A is formatted as Date.

Comment: You could use the macro recorder, do this the manual way, and then look at the vba that the macro recorder generates in order to get an idea of how to do it yourself. (You can select the area with the data, CTRL+T to create a table and then sort Column a by clicking on the dropdown)

Comment: Or, instead of selecting all the columns, as suggested by @QHarr, if your table is contiguous, select only a **single** cell within the table, and the sort wizard should expand to encompass the entire range.